# C# HMACSHA1 vs PHP hash_hmac

Tags: c#, php, sha1, hmacsha1

I am trying to connect to an API to get an access token using PHP and the only hashing example code is written in C#. This is the C# version:

```
private static string GetHMACSignature(string privatekey, string message)
        {
            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] keyByte = encoding.GetBytes(privatekey);
            Console.WriteLine("Key: "+ToReadableByteArray(keyByte));

            System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1 hmacsha1 = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1(keyByte);
            byte[] messageBytes = encoding.GetBytes(message);
            Console.WriteLine("Message: "+ToReadableByteArray(messageBytes));
            byte[] hashmessage = hmacsha1.ComputeHash(messageBytes);
            Console.WriteLine("Hash: "+ToReadableByteArray(hashmessage));
            return Convert.ToBase64String(hashmessage);
        }
```

With a **privatekey** of "a1" and **message** of "b1", you get the following:

```
Key: 97, 49
Message: 98, 49
Hash: 219, 205, 149, 90, 235, 40, 133, 252, 91, 27, 240, 61, 201, 173, 220, 76, 73, 248, 92, 212
282VWusohfxbG/A9ya3cTEn4XNQ=
```

When I try to run the equivalent in PHP, I get the same bytes, but the hash is different:

```
$key = 'a1';
$message = 'b1';
$hmac = hash_hmac('sha1', $key, $message, true);
$hmac_base64 = base64_encode($hmac);

echo 'KEY BYTES: '.implode(',',$this->getByteArray($key)).'<br>';
echo 'MESSAGE BYTES: '.implode(',',$this->getByteArray($message)).'<br>';
echo 'HMAC BYTES: '.implode(',',$this->getByteArray($hmac)).'<br>';
echo 'HMAC: '.$hmac_base64;

function getByteArray($text) {
     $secretBytes = array();
        for($i = 0; $i < strlen($text); $i++)
         {
           $secretBytes[] = ord($text[$i]);
         }

     return $secretBytes;
}
```

Result:

```
KEY BYTES: 97,49
MESSAGE BYTES: 98,49
HMAC BYTES: 3,162,147,8,198,26,126,189,195,122,228,215,10,18,187,216,22,151,202,237
HMAC: A6KTCMYafr3DeuTXChK72BaXyu0=
```

What am I doing wrong? A lot of the problems I've found on here say to set the binary output of hash_hmac to true in PHP, which I've done. Originally my message had return (\r) and newline chars (\n) in it so I thought it might have been an ASCII conversion issue, but running it with **a1** and **b1** as key and message still don't result in matching hashes, even though the byte arrays match. Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about `PHP`, but according to the [documentation on `hash_hmac`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php) it looks as if you might have the `$key` and `$data` parameters reversed.

From the documentation:

> hash_hmac ( string $algo , string $data , string $key [, bool $raw_output = FALSE ] ) : string

So, it looks like you're passing the `$message` as the key and `$key` as the message.

Answer (score 0):

That was it, I had the key and message reversed. Thank you!